# I want to change the Color of Rows of Table using JQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the Color of Rows.
Like,

Change the color of of TR For Every 5 Rows.
first 5 rows Green(0-4 Rows),
Next five rows Red(5-9 Rows),
Next five rows Yellow(10-14 Rows)
and so on......

Comment: if you can add some sample code to your question, that will be more clear.

Comment: How do you populate the rows?

Comment: like <table><tr> <td>id </td> <td>IE10001900</td> </tr> <tr> <td>description</td> <td>Users are unable to make any calls in Zagreb site. Phone lines do not connec</td> </tr> <tr> <td>priority</td> <td>1</td> </tr> <tr> <td>id</td> <td>IE10001901</td> </tr> <tr> <td>description</td> <td>Users are unable to make any calls in Zagreb site. Phone lines do not connect</td> </tr> <tr> <td>priority</td> <td>2</td> </table> </tr> In above table I want to change the color of id based on priority.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something as below , check the index of each element and than apoply the backgroud color as you want ....thiw will work for you easily..

```
$('#table tr').each(function(index)
{   
    if( index < 5) 
     $(this).css("background-color", "#000000"); //change color code as you need
    else if( index < 10) 
     $(this).css("background-color", "#0000FF"); //change color code as you need
    else if( index < 15) 
     $(this).css("background-color", "#00FF00"); //change color code as you need
  //////go on for others

});
```

Comment: A slightly easier-to-use syntax may be `if (index < 5) {} else if (index < 10) {} else if ...`

Comment: @arxanas - yes you are right ...upated asnwer according to that

Comment: Why would you use `$(this).css("background-color", "#000000")` when `this.style.backgroundColor = '#000000'` is less to type and faster to execute?

Comment: @RobG Probably for consistency. It tends to be confusing if you start using non-jQuery and jQuery code together.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post what you tried so far, so read the documentation below. Its simple, but you Whois always do your OWN research before ask!
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy

Answer (score 1):

Try this - a pure CSS solution.

```
// n starts from 0 to infinity. 
// for n+1
//     0+1 = 1
//     1+1 = 2
//     2+1 = 3
//     ... so on...

table tr:nth-child(n+1) {
  color: green;
}
table tr:nth-child(n+6) {
  color: red;
}
table tr:nth-child(n+11) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/29zrT/

More info: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: This will work in all latest browsers, but not in the Great IE 6.

Comment: hi, Solution was good but I wanted to change the color of the tr based on Priority............................................................Like if td value is 5 Change ot to red                                     if td value is 4 Change ot to green

Comment: like 
<table><tr>
<td>id </td>
<td>IE10001900</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>description</td>
<td>Users are unable to make any calls in Zagreb site. Phone lines do not connec</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>priority</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>IE10001901</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>description</td>
<td>Users are unable to make any calls in Zagreb site. Phone lines do not connect</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>priority</td>
<td>2</td> </table>
</tr>  In above table I want to change the color of id based on priority.....

Comment: You mean  id description and priority should have say green color if priority is 1. If it is 2 then make 3 rows red...so on?

Comment: would like to see it. Share it on jsfiddle.net. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A version of shiplu's code:

```
var t = document.getElementById("tbl");
rows = t.rows;
var colours = ['yellow','green','red'];
var group = 5;
var k = colours.length * group;

for(var j=0, jLen = rows.length; j<jLen; j++){
    rows[j].style.backgroundColor = colours[(j%k)/group | 0];
}
```

That will make rows the same colour in sets of 5. If there are more than 15 rows (number of grouped rows times number of colours), it will start the pattern again.